# Having trouble writing a query using the MAX function

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, oracle12c

I have a table of comments users have made about a product:

```
FBID  L_ID  Comments                            Comments_TS                User
110   9885  Testing counting of feedback IDs    07-APR-17 02.52.01.495927000 PM     AMOWIN
111   9885  Test how adding additional comments 07-APR-17 02.52.56.357410000 PM     AMOWIN
112   9911  Test the duplication of plans on    07-APR-17 03.09.27.885587000 PM     AMOWIN
113   9950  Testing pending for source doc      10-APR-17 12.03.19.303782000 PM     AMOWIN
116  10218  testing initial feedback sent       02-MAY-17 09.55.59.174925000 AM     AMOWIN
126  12758  Testing Feedback, Get Next Disabled 12-JUN-17 09.41.15.979093000 AM     AMOWIN
127  12758  jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj       12-JUN-17 11.17.23.742109000 AM     MABAXT
128  12758  Testing status                      12-JUN-17 12.05.32.354178000 PM     SWMART
129  12758  Testing returning to CSE            12-JUN-17 12.06.09.276945000 PM     AMOWIN
130  12758  2nd Test                            12-JUN-17 01.52.08.540984000 PM     AMOWIN
```

What I need to do is only get the record with the last (i.e. most recent) comment.  I've tried this but it's not even close:

```
SELECT MAX(Comments_TS), L_ID, COMMENTS 
FROM F_FEEDBACK FB1 
Group By L_ID, Comments;
```

I need to eventually link this back to the product table by L_ID (short for Line_ID), so I need the last comment made (by the Comment_TS field, which is a timestamp) for each L_ID.  I'm using Oracle 12C, but if anyone can do straight SQL I can figure it out from there.  Not sure why I can't get my head around this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this with a `MAX...KEEP..DENSE_RANK` approach.

```
select l_id, 
       max(comments) keep ( dense_rank first order by comments_ts desc), 
       max(comments_ts) 
from d
group by l_id;
```

Some informal bench-marking I did a while back (which may be outdated), indicated that this uses less resources (memory, specifically) than the analytic `row_number()` approach.

Comment: I agree - if all is needed is this aggregate query (as seems to be the case), then mocking it up with analytic functions does too much work.

Comment: I went with this because it seemed simpler and worked for me, but both answers did work.  I'm giving Matt the checkmark only because Gordon has plenty of rep already.  :o)

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
select fb.*
from f_feedback
order by comments_ts desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you need this for each `l_id`, then use `row_number()`:

```
select fb.*
from (select fb.*,
             row_number() over (partition by l_id order by comments_ts desc) as seqnum
      from f_feedback fb
     ) fb
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want all comments with the same, most recent, time stamp, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Probably meant to remove `fetch first 1 row only` from the second query

Comment: I do need it by l_id, but your code only returned 1 line in total.  There should at least be 1 line for every L_id.

Comment: @AaronDietz - I think you're right, when I took that line out it seemed to work.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - What do you mean by **at least** one line for every `L_ID`? Can there be two comments for the same `L_ID` with exactly the same timestamp? And if so, do you need to return both, or all of them if more than two? That is the weakness of Matthew's aggregate solution; you can only return one row per `L_ID` in that case, and you will need Gordon's analytic functions approach. But, to get all rows with the most recent timestamp, you must change `ROW_NUMBER` to `RANK` (keep everything else the same).

Comment: @mathguy You are right.  But, in a system where comments are entered by humans and the requirement is to show the most recent one, I cannot imagine they would want to see two "most recent" comments just because they happened to come in at exactly the same nanosecond.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - That is right, but there are at least two exceptions. (1) A process collects comments and then inserts them all in the table in one INSERT transaction. If the TS column is populated with SYSTIMESTAMP (as it is, unfortunately, at least sometimes), then the timestamp will be the same for all comments. (2) Even worse, in some organizations the same comment is inserted as several rows, perhaps one paragraph per row (or some other device to keep each string below the 4000 byte limit for VARCHAR2). Then we want all those rows.  Which is why I asked the OP for clarification!

Comment: The number of users in this app is relatively small.  As such, the odds of 2 comments happening in the exact same nanosecond are small enough so that I don't believe precision to that degree is necessary.

Comment: Gordon - This answer worked, and I thank you for your time!